# How to update dateTime into SQL Server database before the application ends

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am a newbie of vb.net and I encountering a headache problem.

Here's my scenario: I have a form named `frmLogin`, when the user success to login into the system, the `datetime` will be updated into a column named `lastLogin` in my database `AdminList` table.

After that, a form named `frmMainPage` will be shown.

Before the application ended, I want to update the `datetime` into a column named `lastLogout` in my database `AdminList` table.

I could update the `dateTime` into database when the user login, but
unfortunately, I couldn't update the `datetime` into database before the application ended.

```
Private Sub frmMainPageClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim zLogout As Integer
    Dim zdTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=USER-PC;Password=;Trusted_Connection=yes;Initial Catalog=BestSmileShop;data source=localhost")        
    Dim cmdLogout As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE AdminList SET lastLogout = '" & zdTime & "' WHERE adminID = '" & lblAdminID.Text & "'", conn)
    conn.Open()
    zLogout = cmdLogout.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    End
End Sub
```

Can anyone explains what is the problem I am having? Please help, Thank You. :)

Comment: So you are successfully updating the column in your database when they login, but not when they logout/end application? I'm a little confused, can you try and clear up a bit?

Comment: Don't you need to associate the OleDbCommand with the OleDbConnection?  `cmdLogout.Connection = conn` should do it.  (I'd put it after conn.Open())

Comment: BTW, since you're using SQL Server, it makes more sense to use the objects in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace (instead of the OleDB objects.)

Comment: @DMason, I had added `cmdLogout.Connection = conn` after `conn.open()` but it doesn't work. 
About the oledb object, my lecturer wants me to use this to do our project.

Comment: Actually, I missed the line where you declare (Dim) cmdLogout--it includes the OleDbConnection in the constructor.  So my previous comment is moot....

Comment: I'd add some error handling next.  If you're getting exceptions, it will help to see exception messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application just closed without error...

Comment: To test the command, I tried to change this line<br>
`Dim cmdLogout As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE AdminList SET lastLogout = '" & zdTime & "' WHERE adminID = '" & lblAdminID.Text & "'", conn)`<br>
to <br>
`Dim cmdLogout As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE AdminList2 SET lastLogout2 = '" & zdTime & "' WHERE adminID2 = '" & lblAdminID.Text & "'", conn)` <br>
and it shows me error `column not found`, that means the problem isn't in command.

Comment: Let's go back to the original code you posted.  Can you put a breakpoint on `conn.Open()`?  When your code breaks, hover your mouse over `lblAdminID.Text`.  Is there a valid value there?

Comment: yes, it is valid. Because it is shared from frmLogin.txtAdminID.

Comment: all of the objects in the OleDbCommand seems all have return a valid value, I think the problem is only at the ExecuteNonQuery(). Don't you think so?

Comment: oh... I found where's the problem... as you said, the `lblAdminID.Text` returned the value `Welcome back, test!`... That's why it wont works properly. Thanks for willing to help me and sorry for wasting your time because of my clumsiness :)

Comment: VillagerA, you need to reference @DMason or else he will not get an alert of the message you meant for him/her. This way he/she can put his/her answer down, which you can mark as answered. This way we don't all read the issue and 20 comments just to find out it is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh... I found where's the problem... 
As @DMason suggestion, after I put a breakpoint on `conn.Open()` and execute the application, the `lblAdminID.Text` returned the value `Welcome back, test!`...
 That's why it won't works properly. 
So, it is just my clumsiness.